# Fixing a Wordpress Plug-in's HTTPS error in PHP, mixed content error when I know which files are creating the error?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, ssl

I am trying to fix another developer's Wordpress plugin that I would like to utilize but being my wordpress blog is 100% HTTPS (Shared SSL Certificate with CDN) it creates mixed content errors on the admin panel as well as if displayed on the website. I am not a PHP guy but I have done a lot of coding over the years and code review so I would like to try to work through this.

All other plug-ins on my website do not require me to use any forced SSL method, and I have already followed the guides for implementing SSL / HTTPS. I have no other SSL/HTTPS or mixed content errors and *I do not want to go back to having to use it* as it created other issues.

I have used the Firefox Inspector and know which files generate the issue:
http:///wp-content/plugins//resources/scripts/.js
http:///wp-content/plugins//resources/css/themes/default/jquery-ui.css
As well as it serves up images for the plug-in as HTTP.

The `Plugins.php` file that I open in Firefox shows it registered as HTTP vs. HTTPS.

What I have looked at:
I have scanned the code for HTTP and not found any HTTP outside of the header docs and confirmed that the plug-in gets its GoogleFonts and Google CoreChart from https://www.google.com/jsapi.

I have done some reading and am not clear on "this.url" usage or if this is the source or not but have read others have the problem.

I have scanned the code and did not see any paths that were not ended with a `\` that were not parameters to a specific file themselves.

```
     * sets up the object with the AJAX url and security nonce, also retrieves language properties
 */
setup: function(url, nonce, pluginUrl, userId, callbackFn, skipLoadGlobals) {
    if(!PI.ajaxSetup) {
        // create custom widgets
        initPICustom();

        PI.globals.pluginUrl = pluginUrl;
        PI.userId = userId;
        this.url = url;
        this.nonce = nonce;

        if(!skipLoadGlobals) {
            this.loadGlobalData(callbackFn);
        }
        else {
            callbackFn();
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('Ajax setup function already called');
    }
},
```

All of the other references to the URL look something like the following:

```
    getUserOldestResultYear: function(userId, callbackFn) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: PI.Ajax.url
```

At least one of the files being reported is the [Datatables plug-in](http://www.datatables.net/download/download) that is about two years old, and [JQueryUI 1.6 or 1.7](http://jqueryui.com/download/) that is at least 6 years old.

I do not currently use the plugin and would like to. This plug-in is still updated is updated about once or twice a year, the developer has their freeware code on GitHub. So I would like to take a shot at fixing it or at very minimum give the developer very specific direction on how to fix it if I figure out most of it using my test site.

I cannot provide a link at this time to the specific site because I only activate the plug-in when I am actively working on it due to it resulting in errors on the rest of my site when I due activate it. I am looking for guidance on how to further diagnosis the issue and hopefully also how to fix it.

So my questions are:

1. Is there anything else specific thing I should be looking for in the code to possibly identify the source of these HTTP calls that I may be able to fix relatively easily in the code?
2. Would simply upgrading JQueryUI and DataTables and likely fix the issue or is this a red herring?
3. IF #2 is in the affirmative, I downloaded DataTables and the latest JQueryUI would attempting to upgrade the app to use it being they are so far behind likely end up in a total rewrite or is it something that is relatively managable? (i.e. I have some time but not a lot of time to try to fix this).
4. If the AJAX thing is related, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The root of my problem was none of the above and it was a change in the way Wordpress internal variables worked.

The plug-in I was attempting to troubleshoot was utilizing the following:

```
define('WPA_PLUGIN_DIR', WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . WPA_PLUGIN_NAME);
define('WPA_PLUGIN_URL', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/' . WPA_PLUGIN_NAME);
```

New Code which per these two links stating to [do not use the internal Wordpress variables](https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/wp_plugin_url-doesnt-take-ssl-into-account) and to [use these instead](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) took care of it in the primary plugin PHP file.

```
define('WPA_PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ));
define('WPA_PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ));
```

But to recap my questions:

1. Checking the wordpress codex was what I needed to do to determine
   depreciated methods were being used.
2. Yes the old versions were red herrings and had nothing to do with it.
3. N/A
4. N/A